# java.net site not available for downloading JSF libs

Tags: jsf-2.2

I have tried to download JSF2 libs from the official web site for two days (mojara project): http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/javaserverfaces-139869.html 
But, the website is not available and it is displayed that the java.net site has closed.

Please, how can I get the JSF2 libs otherwise.

Thanks in advance

Comment: These kinds of questions do not belong in SO. And the site works for me

Comment: The site works but when you click on mojara project <javaserverfaces.java.net> it does not work

Comment: https://dcd.java.net has closed too.

Comment: Project home appears to be here now: https://github.com/javaserverfaces/mojarra. There are releases there if you don't use maven. But there is still a pointer to java.net. No browsable documentation visible right now.

Answer (score 2):

Take them form an Maven Repository

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.14</version>
</dependency>
```

https://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.sun.faces%7Cjsf-api%7C2.2.14%7Cjar

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.14</version>
</dependency>
```

https://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.sun.faces%7Cjsf-api%7C2.2.14%7Cjar

Comment: Thank you. I have downloaded it now